# Why can't I assign a struct variable using curly brackets {}?

Tags: c, debugging, sdl-2

I have the following code, why does Visual Studio underly the first bracket `{` in `playerObj.cropImg = { 0, 0, 45, 32 };` and return an error `error C2059: syntax error : '{'` when I compile ?

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct obj
{
    SDL_Surface *pSprite;
    SDL_Texture *pTexture;
    SDL_Rect cropImg;
    SDL_Rect pos;
} obj;

obj playerObj;

void playerObj_init(unsigned char * filename, SDL_Renderer * pRenderer)
{
    playerObj.cropImg = { 0, 0, 45, 32 };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code attempts *assignment*.

*Initialization* is when you provide a value for the variable as part of a declaration.

Assignment is when you provide new values for a variable that already exists; this occurs in a *statement* (not a declaration).

In C90, brace-enclosed initializers can only be used in declarations. In C99 you can have literals of struct type but you have to specify the type as part of the syntax (it would be too complicated to have the compiler try to deduce it):

```
playerObj.cropImg = (SDL_Rect) { 0, 0, 45, 32 };
```

An alternative that works in C90 is to write:

```
SDL_Rect const newRect = { 0, 0, 45, 32 };
playerObj.cropImg = newRect;
```

and the compiler should optimize it.

NB. Consider using designated initializers to help with code maintainability. In either situation,

```
 { .w = 45, .h = 32 }
```

Comment: Why do you have to use `const` in SDL_Rect const `newRect`. Will `playerObj.cropImg` be constant too ? If I use `{ .w = 45, .h = 32 }` will I be able to just do `playerObj.cropImg.w= 29` afterwards ?

`playerObj.cropImg = (SDL_Rect) { 0, 0, 45, 32 };` is terrific thank you for your help !

Comment: No, the `const` is just an optimization hint (and prevents you accdidentally changing `newRect`). It only affects `newRect`, not anything you copy out of `newRect`.   Yes, you can do that afterwards.

Comment: got it, by the way can I also use `SDL_Rect cropImg = {.x, .y, .w, .h };` in the `typedef struct obj` declaration ?

Comment: No (and you can't put values there either)